# Do most of the high ranking Inquisitors possess psychic abilities?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I believe that all senior inquisitors that I've read about - Eisenhorn, Ravenor, Jarldottyr, Heldane - were all powerful psykers. From the stories that I've read I think only Amberley Vail (from the Ciaphas Cain novels) didn't show outright psychic skills (which doesn't mean she didn't have them).

Are psychic abilities a job requirement for ascending into higher levels of Inquisition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No they are not a requirement, but could certainly be a benefit.

In the [Grey Knight](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Grey_Knights_(Novel_Series)) series we met [Gholic Ren-Sar Valinov](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gholic_Ren-Sar_Valinov), an Inquisitor of the Ordo Malleus who falls to Chaos. And [Nyxos](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Nyxos), an Inquisitor Lord of the Ordo Malleus.

Neither exhibit any psyker powers at all throughout the GK series. We see both involved in quite a few extended battles as well.

At one stage Valinov says something to the effect of:

> I don't need the powers of a psyker, I'm quite capable without them.

So going by these two examples, I would assume that you wouldn't *need* to be a psyker to rise up through the ranks of the Inquisition, but it could obviously help when rooting out those pesky [heretics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSvha.jpg).